# Angular change detection on Template Reference Variables for property binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I'm playing around with template reference variables. And thought of using its value to set the disabled property on a button. i.e disable a button unless the input field is non-empty. I expected the following code to work but the button stays disabled even after some value is entered in the input.

**Why does Angular change detection not work in this case?**

**Is there another way to do achieve this using ONLY template reference variables?**

The code is written in Angular 8 and node 12.16.2

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input #hello type="text" class="form-control" id="01">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="hello.value.length === 0">Deactivate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **ngForm** combined with **ngModel** directive to achieve this,

```
<form #testForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="hello" ngModel class="form-control" id="01">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="testForm.value.hello.length === 0">
            Deactivate
        </button>
    </div>
</form>

{{testForm.value|json}}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtdm4k?file=src/app/app.component.html

For more details, see [this](https://appdividend.com/2018/10/03/angular-ngmodel-directive-example-tutorial/).